# FullCalendar today button

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

Everyone knows how to change the "today" button to read "Today" with a capital T? Thx!

Tried to create my own button recalling the function but I could not find today function.

Should be with customButtons but does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#CalendarioWeb').fullCalendar({
        header:{
            left:'today,prev,next,Today',
            center:'title',
            right:'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        customButtons:{
            Today:{
                text:"Today",
                click:function(){
                    "today"
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What library are you using? Your code doesn't look like the examples I see at https://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: @Barmar it's fullcalendar 3 or below - it used to be a jQuery plugin, years ago. OP is just using an outdated version for some reason. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3#toc

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, now working with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#PruebaCalendario').fullCalendar({
        header:{
            left:'today,prev,next,Today',
            center:'title',
            right:'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        customButtons:{
            Today:{
                text:"Today",
                click:function(){
                    $('#PruebaCalendario').fullCalendar('today');
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't jusdt post code, explain what you changed and why.